# How to send a message in an "async def on_raw_reaction_add" discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
      global verstuurd_id
      global game
      print(payload)
      #await message.channel.send('Er is een emoji toegevoegd')
      if payload.message_id == verstuurd_id and game == True and payload.user_id != self.user.id:
        print("Er is gereageerd")
        if payload.emoji.name =='➡':
          pass
          #await payload.channel_id.send('You answered right')
      else:
        print('Er is iets fout gegaan')
```

I want to send a message in the discord channel but I am not able to in an `async def on_raw_reaction_add`. Does anyone know how to?

Answer (score 2):

In the [`on_raw_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) event you receive a [`discord.RawReactionActionEvent`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) object. This object doesn't has an attribute that would give you a channel object. But it does has `channel_id` which you can use to get an actual [`discord.TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel) object to send your message.

You can also get a [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) object of the user who added the reaction.

You are attempting to call `send()` on an `int` which is `payload.channel_id` in this case. To get the channel object(since  you have the channel id):

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
# Or
channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, id=payload.channel_id)
```

Now you can send the message by calling `send()` on that object:

```py
 async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
      global verstuurd_id
      global game
      print(payload)
      if payload.message_id == verstuurd_id and game == True and payload.user_id != self.user.id:
        print("Er is gereageerd")
        if payload.emoji.name =='➡':
          channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
          await channel.send('You answered right')
      else:
        print('Er is iets fout gegaan')
```